# Which part of the targetDataLine should I use in order to transcribe audio into frequency data by using FFT algorithm?

Tags: java, fft, javasound

I am trying to find the input for FFT so as to get the time-frequency data of each audio input. I've went through some website and I know the input should be obtained from `targetDataLine`. I've made a program to capture audio data and it works.

Here is my code of printing the `targetDataLine` (after collecting audio data)

```
System.out.println
("TargetDataLine buffer size is " + targetDataLine.getBufferSize()
                                        + "\n" + "TargetDataLine format is "
                                        + targetDataLine.getFormat().toString() + "\n"
                                        + "TargetDataLine info is "
                                        + targetDataLine.getLineInfo().toString());
```

and here's is the system output:

```
TargetDataLine buffer size is 8000
TargetDataLine format is PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2   bytes/frame, little-endian
TargetDataLine info is interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
```

I am confused about which part of this output can be used for FFT algorithm. Or, should we get the input from some where else instead of `targetDataLine`?

Any help of idea is appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read() method is used to get data from a TargetDataLine. This puts audio data into a buffer which you may be able to directly ship to the fft analysis. Not knowing the specs of what the fft requires, you may have to do some file/format conversion first. For example, you may have to convert the audio bytes into normalized floats.
[Using Files and Format Converters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) is the Oracle tutorial that has some coverage of this process. The first code example has a section in the comments that says "//Here, do something useful with the audio data that's now in the audioBytes array..." This is where the individual bytes of the audio stream (whether from an AudioInputLine or TargetDataLine) are exposed and can be operated on prior to shipping to your FFT analysis.